# Proof of Wald's Equation: Why do we need this statement?

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i]= \mu$ and $Var[X_i]= \sigma^2$.

Let $\tau$ be a non-negative integer-valued random variable independent of $X_i$.

Now consider $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

We want to show that $\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau} \mid \tau] = \mu \tau$ a.s. for $\mathbb{E}[\tau]< \infty$.

In the proof there first is shown that $\mathbb{E}[|S_{\tau}|]\leq \mathbb{E}[|X_i|]\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ using the monotone convergence theorem.

Then we calculate

$\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau} \mid \tau] = \mathbb{E}[S_k] \mid_{k=\tau}=\mu k \mid_{k = \tau}= \mu \tau$.

What confuses me now is: do we really need that statement above about the absolute value derived using the monotone convergence theorem? Under which circumstances is the second calculation (with the conditional expectation) valid? I would suggest that we calculated this to justify the use of dominated convergence, but where do we use dominated convergence in the following?

Then it is mentioned that we can use the tower property of conditional expectation to derive that $\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau}]= \mu \mathbb{E}[\tau]$. Do we need the above statement for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear a priori that $S_\tau$  is integrable, and this rests on the assumption that $\tau$ has a finite expectation. In that way, the computations are justified.

We indeed have 
$$\mathbb E[|S_\tau| ]=\mathbb E\left[ \sum_{j=0}^\infty\mathbf 1_{\tau=j}|S_j|   \right]$$
and we need to switch the expectation with the infinite sum, which is done by monotone convergence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The hint with "integrable" was very useful. So we show that $\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau}]< \infty$ (i.e. $S_{\tau}$ integrable) using the monotone convergence theorem in order to justify the use of conditional expectation? Do we somewhere need the Dominated Convergence Theorem? Because if I remember correctly, I think they gave us the hint that we first should apply monotone and them dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @user136457 I've edited. Indeed, after the "Then we calculate" in your post, the computations need the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: So I thought I got your answer but we talked with another teaching assistant about this topic again and he told us that there is no dominated convergence here but that this is just the definition of conditional expectation. So what is it now?